# Inno Setup use a different icon on a custom form title bar

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

By default, custom forms use the same icon in the title bar as that of the main `WizardForm`, which is the `SetupIconFile`. Is there any way to give a custom form a different icon on it's title bar?

```pascal
[Code]
var
  CustomWindowForm: TForm;

{ Create and show the Custom window }
procedure ShowCustomWindow();
begin
  CustomWindowForm := TForm.Create(WizardForm);
  with CustomWindowForm do
    begin
      BorderStyle := bsSingle;
      Position := poOwnerFormCenter;
      Caption := 'Window Title';
      ClientWidth := ScaleX(400);
      ClientHeight := ScaleY(400);
      Show;
    end;
end;
```

What I need is something like an `Icon` property for `TForm`, but there doesn't appear to be one and I cannot find any information on this anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use WinAPI, particularly [`LoadImage` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadimagew) and [`WM_SETICON` message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-seticon):

```pascal
[Files]
Source: "custom.ico"; Flags: dontcopy

[Code]

const
  IMAGE_ICON = 1;
  LR_LOADFROMFILE = $10;
  WM_SETICON = $80;
  ICON_SMALL = 0;

function LoadImage(
  hInst: Integer; ImageName: string; ImageType: UINT; X, Y: Integer;
  Flags: UINT): THandle; external 'LoadImageW@User32.dll stdcall';

procedure CustomFormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  Icon: THandle;
begin
  ExtractTemporaryFile('custom.ico');
  Icon := LoadImage(
    0, ExpandConstant('{tmp}\custom.ico'), IMAGE_ICON, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
  SendMessage(TForm(Sender).Handle, WM_SETICON, ICON_SMALL, Icon);
end;

var
  CustomWindowForm: TForm;

{ Create and show the custom window }
procedure ShowCustomWindow();
begin
  CustomWindowForm := TForm.Create(WizardForm);
  with CustomWindowForm do
  begin
    { your code }

    OnShow := @CustomFormShow;
    Show;
  end;
end;
```

*(The code is for Unicode version of Inno Setup – The only version as of Inno Setup 6)*

[image]

Comment: Strangely this worked fine for a while and then just stopped working. It seems unreliable sending the message before showing the window. I had to move the `SendMessage` to after `Show` and add a `Refresh`, which seems to have kicked it back into life. Any ideas why this might have suddenly stopped working after it worked fine initially?

Comment: The icon is lost whenever a window handle is recreated. Ideally, one should set the icon in a response to VCL method `CreateWnd` - but that's not possible in Inno Setup. So any change you made to the code, which causes the handle to be recreated in `Show` (what for example some values of `Position` do) will break the code.

Comment: It's indeed safer to move the code after `Show` - but that will actually briefly show the window with the default icon (that's why I set the icon before `Show`). Move only the `SendMessage` after `Show`. Keep time consuming `ExtractTemporaryFile` and  `LoadImage` before. --- Though probably the best solution within limitations of Inno Setup, is to set the icon in `OnShow` event handler - I've updated the code.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thank you for explaining that. I think I moved the order of the `Position` property. Maybe that's what broke it. What you have suggested above, sounds like the best method.

Comment: I actually put the `ExtractTemporaryFile` in `IntializeSetup`, as that seems to be the best place to do that.